# How to send more than two values from one form (takes values from mysql)to another using php $_GET with "? and &"?

Tags: php

I want to retrieve three values from MYsql using PHP and send those 3 values to other form using $_Get function, I am getting values for the first two inputs (atleast outside my required text box). I can't get the third value (P_age)

```
    // in form where I retrieve values from Database and send it to other using "?" and "&"

          $connection=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
          mysql_select_db("Aravind_Database",$connection);
          $v= mysql_query("Select * from patient_details order by P_id");
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($v))
          {           
          echo $row['P_id'];      
          echo "<tr><td>".$row['P_id']."</td><td>".$row['P_name']."</td><td>".$row['P_age']."</td><td>"."<a href=Editing_Patient_Detail.php>Edit</a></td><td><a href=Delete_Patient_Detail.php?P_id=".$row['P_id']."&P_name=".$row['P_name']."&P_age=".$row['P_age'].">Delete</a>";
          }
          mysql_close( $connection);


// form where I try to retrieve values through $_Get


    $connection=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
               mysql_select_db("Aravind_Database",$connection);
               if ($_GET['P_id']!= '')
              {     
                            $v= mysql_query(" Select * from patient_details order by P_id");
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($v))
                            {   
                                  if ($row['P_id'] == $_GET['P_id'])
                                  {
                                   ?> <input type="text" value='<?php echo $_GET['P_id'] ?>' disabled="true" /><br>
 <input type="text" width="145" value='<?php  echo $_GET['P_name'] ?>' disabled="true" /><br>
 <input type="text" value   ='<?php  echo $_GET['P_age']?>' disabled="true" /><br>
 <?php 
                                   break;
                                  }
                            }
                            mysql_close($connection);
              } 


    enter code here
```

Comment: try print_r($_GET); & check what values you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I would include

```
name="myinput_name"
```

in the input tag and also when disabled is true... the GET and POST ignore it... I think you should make it readonly="readonly" instead of disabled